# UINavigationController toolbar buttons not animating when pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have few UIViewControllers embeded in NavigationController, everything is cool when it comes to change screen titles, button titles, hiding/showing navigation bar (top bar) or toolbar (bottom bar), but - I cannot force toolbar buttons to have this animated shadow when pressed, as navigation bar buttons have. What's more, toolbar buttons are as black as toolbar - shouldn't button be slightly lighter color than toolbar?
I hope it's clear, because I couldn't find it nor even come up with reasonable title

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand you whole problem but for the toolbar problem you can give those buttons different colors and also can give an effect of changing color of button which is clicked

```
UIBarButtonItem *toolBtn      =       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Share and Upload"
                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(your_Target)]; 

toolBtn.tintColor               =           [UIColor redColor];
```

Now suppose toolBtn is your first button in toolbar and on click of it you want to change its color then in your target function

```
-(void)your_Target{

   UIBarButtonItem *button1        =           [[your_Toolbar items] objectAtIndex:0];
    button1.tintColor               =           [UIColor brownColor];

// or you can simply loop all toolbar buttons and change the color of only clicked one and for rest keep it default
}
```

Hope this will help you.. and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a black bar (navigation or toolbar), set its `barStyle` to `UIBarStyleBlack` in addition to or instead of tinting it black. This lets it know that the buttons should be tinted differently than if the bar was any other color.